# What is the central columns feature in Phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

There are some questions like [How to use "central columns" in phpmyadmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094375/how-to-use-central-columns-in-phpmyadmin) in Stackoverflow realted to my question. But it does not explain what is the usage of this feature.

What is the central columns feature in Phpmyadmin?

Comment: @jww Thanks, but how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094375/how-to-use-central-columns-in-phpmyadmin become ontopic question?

Comment: The topic you linked does contain its description along with its use.

Answer (score 8):

> Central columns is a phpMyAdmin feature that makes it easy…to copy a
>   column definition to another table.…This can be useful when defining
>   tables…linked by a foreign key.…It's available only in phpMyAdmin 4.3
>   and later…and it requires configuration storage
>
> To add a column to central list, go to table structure page, check the
>   columns you want to include and then simply click on “Add to central
>   columns”. If you want to add all unique columns from more than one
>   table from a database then go to database structure page, check the
>   tables you want to include and then select “Add columns to central
>   list”.